# How to extract the number of comments of a youtube video using Google Chrome Headless and Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, youtube, css-selectors

There is a element in every youtube webpage to show how many comments for the video.
It is such a html structure:

```
<yt-formatted-string class="count-text style-scope ytd-comments-header-renderer">xx Comments</yt-formatted-string>
```

I want to get the number `xx Comments` with selenium.
code1-with head browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
proxy = '127.0.0.1:1080'   
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + proxy)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0lxfilGfak'

driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("return scrollBy(0, 1000);")
comment = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[contains(., 'Comments')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",comment)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[@id='count']").text)
```

With the above python code ,i can get `717 Comments` for `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0lxfilGfak`.

Now i want to get the same number with headless browser in selenium.
code2-with headless browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
proxy = '127.0.0.1:1080'   
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://' + proxy)
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0lxfilGfak'

driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("return scrollBy(0, 1000);")
comment = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[contains(., 'Comments')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",comment)
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[@id='count']").text)
```

Note:there are three lines more in code2 than code1.

```
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Other lines are same both in code2 and code1.

It get stuck in `comment` statement when to execute code2:

```
>>> comment = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[contains(., 'Comments')]")))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Why can't get the element with headless browser in selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. To print the text **xx Comments** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0lxfilGfak")
  driver.execute_script("return scrollBy(0, 1000);")
  subscribe = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[text()='Subscribe']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",subscribe)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h2[@id='count']/yt-formatted-string"))).text)
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0lxfilGfak")
  driver.execute_script("return scrollBy(0, 1000);")
  subscribe = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[text()='Subscribe']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",subscribe)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h2#count>yt-formatted-string"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  717 Comments
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Using Headless Chrome

Using [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0lxfilGfak")
  driver.execute_script("return scrollBy(0, 1000);")
  subscribe = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[text()='Subscribe']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",subscribe)
  # using xpath and text attribute
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//h2[@id='count']/yt-formatted-string"))).text)
  # using cssSelector and get_attribute()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h2#count>yt-formatted-string"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  print("Exiting")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  717 Comments
  717 Comments
  Exiting
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Add line in my setting for `headless` setting:

```
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
```

Or make scroll more longer in y direction.

```
driver.execute_script("return scrollBy(0, 5000);")
```

My xpath expression is more direct.

Comment: Ideally, you should use `add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')` else it would be tougher to guess a good value to `scrollBy()` as the display isn't present.